# Vuejs transition duration auto?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using the Vuejs official router, and am currently working on giving different routes different animations, like in the example here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/transitions.html (see 'Route-Based Dynamic Transition')

My problem is that some transitions need a specific transition durations, and others don't (those I want to specify in the CSS).

I've made a variable that holds the duration to pass to the router, (same as this.transitionName in the router) but I was wondering if there was a way to set this variable to 'auto', for the routes that don't need a duration?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about your setup, so I'll only address modifying the transition duration.

As you can tell, the transitions are using css to manage the transitions.

I've taken the example in the doc you linked (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/transitions/app.js) and added the functionality to override the duration.

```js
const Parent = {
  data() {
    return {
      transitionName: "slide-left",
      transitionDuration: 2.5
    };
  },
  computed: {
    transitionStyle() {
      return {
        'transition-duration': this.transitionDuration +'s'
      }
    }
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    const toDepth = to.path.split("/").length;
    const fromDepth = from.path.split("/").length;
    ///////////////
    // this is where you set the transition duration
    // replace with your own implementation of setting duration
    this.transitionDuration = Math.random()*1.5+0.5; 
    ///////////////
    this.transitionName = toDepth < fromDepth ? "slide-right" : "slide-left";
    next();
  },
  template: `
    <div class="parent">
      <h2>Parent</h2>
      {{transitionStyle}}
      <transition :name="transitionName">
        <router-view class="child-view" :style="transitionStyle"></router-view>
      </transition>
    </div>
  `
};
```

This will override the duration by in-lining the style
You would still need to find a way to get the intended duration within `beforeRouteUpdate`, but I'll leave that up to you.

you can have a look at a working pen here: https://codepen.io/scorch/pen/LOPpYd
Note that the effect is only applied to the `parent` component, so animation on home(`/`) will not be affected